# Linq Contains for Integer Array

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I need to fetch the records from Table based on ID's in Linq C#. Linq has Contains which works well for String but anyone can help me how i can implement it with Integer Array.

```
int[] ServiceID = {1, 4, 5}

var result = from table in _context.Table where table.ServiceID.Contains(ServiceID)
```

I am looking similar filter for Int Array. Please help if anyone have any idea.

Comment: You just need to reverse the order: `ServiceID.Contains(table.ServiceID)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `int[] ServiceID`

Don't call your local variable `ServiceID` -

1. local variables should be called in camelCase,
2. variables representing sets should be plural,
3. you have a property called ServiceID on your table - calling the local variable the same is a recipe for confusion

The pattern you need to ask is not "does my table.ServiceId contain these wanted serviceIDs", it's "do these wanted serviceIDs contain the table serviceID":

```
    int[] wantedServiceIDs = {1, 4, 5}

    var result = from table in _context.Table 
                 where wantedServiceIDs.Contains(table.ServiceID)
```

In SQL terms, this will be translated to

```
   FROM table
   WHERE serviceId IN (1,4,5)
```

The confusion, in you're familiar with SQL, is that this is the flip of what you asked for ..

You're supposed to write a LINQ of `list.Contains(column)` and SQL needs it flipped over to `column IN(list)` - but of course, when you look at the *english language* it's logical - *x Contains y* is the flip of *y IN x*. Familiarity with SQL's IN, and that the english words "IN" and "Contains" themselves meaning virtually the same thing probably leads a lot of people to try `column.Contains(list)` when what they need is the inverse

Another possible point of confsuon is that when people think about a column of data in an SQL table, they see multiple values.. But really the database/code only considers one row's worth of data at a time, so it's `multiple.Contains(single)` or `single IN (multiple)`, and never `multipleX.Contains(multipleY)`

---

You can also ask "are any of the wanted service ids equal to the table service id"

```
var result = from table in _context.Table where 
  wantedServiceIDs.Any(wantedId => table.ServiceID == wantedId)
```

This latter form is trickier, because it often leads you to believe you can use complex expressions to refine your `table`, and you can't so I'd strive to avoid using it.. For example

```
var wantedServices = new[] { new Service{ ID = 1, name = ""}, new Service{ ID = 2, name = ""} };

//this wouldn't work/not be translatable to SQL
var result = from table in _context.Table where 
  wantedServices.Any(wantedService => table.ServiceID == wantedService.ID)
```

Using the simple "list of ID ints" .Contains discourages you from trying this form

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this (using `Contains`). also change you array variable name to  `ServiceIDs`

```
int[] ServiceIDs = {1, 4, 5}  
var result = ServiceID.Where(i => ServiceIDs.Contains(i.OrderId));
```